# Flutter run command fails only on Android

Tags: flutter, gradle

I've been having this problem since I've recently upgraded Flutter from 1.22 to 2.2. Every time I try to run the app `flutter run` the build fails. Now, this happens only on Android, so I'm assuming it's a Gradle issue (I don't really know Gradel). I've tried switching to master, stable and beta channels of Flutter -- none of which fixed the issue. I've also tried `flutter pub cache repair` and `flutter clean` to no effect. I then finally completely reinstalled Flutter (I deleted the flutter src folder and downloaded the [lastest](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows). Any help is appreciated!

Command outputs:

```
> flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.985], locale en-GB)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.56.2)
[√] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

```
> flutter run

Using hardware rendering with device sdk gphone x86 arm. If you notice graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider_windows-0.0.4+3/lib/src/path_provider_windows_real.dart:126:25: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
          knownFolderID.addressOf, KF_FLAG_DEFAULT, NULL, pathPtrPtr);  
                        ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:1067:7: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'LOGFONT'.
 - 'LOGFONT' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
      addressOf.cast<Uint8>().elementAt(28).cast<Utf16>();
      ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:1112:29: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'ENUMLOGFONTEX'.
 - 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  LOGFONT get elfLogFont => addressOf.cast<LOGFONT>().ref;
                            ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:1114:29: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'ENUMLOGFONTEX'.
 - 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  String get elfFullName => addressOf
                            ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:1120:26: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'ENUMLOGFONTEX'.
 - 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  String get elfStyle => addressOf
                         ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:1126:27: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'ENUMLOGFONTEX'.
 - 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  String get elfScript => addressOf
                          ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2688:7: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'OSVERSIONINFO'.
 - 'OSVERSIONINFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
      addressOf.cast<Uint8>().elementAt(20).cast<Utf16>().unpackString(128);
      ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2699:11: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'OSVERSIONINFO'.
 - 'OSVERSIONINFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        ..addressOf.cast<Uint8>().elementAt(20).value = 0;
          ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2744:24: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO'.
 - 'BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  String get szName => addressOf
                       ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2837:7: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO'.
 - 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
      addressOf.cast<Uint8>().elementAt(BTH_MAX_PIN_SIZE).value;
      ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2840:5: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO'.
 - 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
    addressOf.cast<Uint8>().elementAt(BTH_MAX_PIN_SIZE).value =
    ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2845:28: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO'.
 - 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
      String.fromCharCodes(addressOf.cast<Uint8>().asTypedList(pinLength));
                           ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2853:7: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO'.
 - 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
      addressOf.cast<Uint8>().elementAt(idx).value = pinData[idx];      
      ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/com/combase.dart:38:31: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  final iid = GUID.allocate().addressOf;
                              ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/com/combase.dart:56:33: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  final clsid = GUID.allocate().addressOf;
                                ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/winrt/winrt_helpers.dart:86:40: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  final riidCalendar = GUID.allocate().addressOf;
                                       ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/generated/IDesktopWallpaper.dart:197:38: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'COMObject'.
 - 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
    final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
                                     ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/generated/IDesktopWallpaper.dart:200:49: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(CLSID_DesktopWallpaper).addressOf,
                                                ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/generated/IDesktopWallpaper.dart:203:48: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(IID_IDesktopWallpaper).addressOf,
                                               ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/generated/IFileOpenDialog.dart:58:38: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'COMObject'.
 - 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
    final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
                                     ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/generated/IFileOpenDialog.dart:61:47: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(CLSID_FileOpenDialog).addressOf,
                                              ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/generated/IFileOpenDialog.dart:64:46: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(IID_IFileOpenDialog).addressOf,
                                             ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/generated/IFileSaveDialog.dart:99:38: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'COMObject'.
 - 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
    final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
                                     ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/generated/IFileSaveDialog.dart:102:47: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(CLSID_FileSaveDialog).addressOf,
                                              ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/generated/IFileSaveDialog.dart:105:46: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(IID_IFileSaveDialog).addressOf,
                                             ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/generated/IKnownFolderManager.dart:164:38: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'COMObject'.
 - 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
    final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
                                     ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/generated/IKnownFolderManager.dart:167:51: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(CLSID_KnownFolderManager).addressOf,
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/generated/IKnownFolderManager.dart:170:50: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(IID_IKnownFolderManager).addressOf,
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/generated/INetworkListManager.dart:128:38: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'COMObject'.
 - 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
    final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
                                     ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/generated/INetworkListManager.dart:131:51: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(CLSID_NetworkListManager).addressOf,
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/generated/INetworkListManager.dart:134:50: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(IID_INetworkListManager).addressOf,
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/generated/IWbemLocator.dart:82:38: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'COMObject'.
 - 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
    final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
                                     ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/generated/IWbemLocator.dart:84:68: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
    final hr = CoCreateInstance(GUID.fromString(CLSID_WbemLocator).addressOf,
                                                                   ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/generated/IWbemLocator.dart:85:64: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        nullptr, CLSCTX_ALL, GUID.fromString(IID_IWbemLocator).addressOf, ptr);
                                                               ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/utf8.dart:63:33: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'Utf8'.
 - 'Utf8' is from 'package:ffi/src/utf8.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/utf8.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  String toString() => fromUtf8(addressOf);
                                ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:1111:7: Error: Struct 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class ENUMLOGFONTEX extends Struct {
      ^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2835:7: Error: Struct 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO extends Struct {
      ^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2960:7: Error: Struct 'EXCEPINFO' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class EXCEPINFO extends Struct {}
      ^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2966:7: Error: Struct 'PROPERTYKEY' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class PROPERTYKEY extends Struct {}
      ^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2973:7: Error: Struct 'PROPVARIANT' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class PROPVARIANT extends Struct {}
      ^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2978:7: Error: Struct 'SAFEARRAY' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class SAFEARRAY extends Struct {}
      ^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2985:7: Error: Struct 'CLSID' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class CLSID extends Struct {}
      ^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2992:7: Error: Struct 'STATSTG' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class STATSTG extends Struct {}
      ^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2999:7: Error: Struct 'NLM_SIMULATED_PROFILE_INFO' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class NLM_SIMULATED_PROFILE_INFO extends Struct {}
      ^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/utf8.dart:23:7: Error: Struct 'Utf8' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class Utf8 extends Struct {
      ^
class Utf16 extends Struct {
      ^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/allocation.dart:47:33: Error: Expected type 'T' to be a valid and instantiated subtype of 'NativeType'.
  final int totalSize = count * sizeOf<T>();
                                ^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1035

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        12.8s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Have you tried the standard solution in the terminal? `flutter clean`  then `flutter pub get`

Comment: @АлександрИнженер Yes I already did that and it didn't change anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running the following commands:

```
flutter pub upgrade

flutter pub outdated

flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
```

If that doesn't work, double check if all your packages are up to date, then add this under your dependency overrides in your pubspec.yaml

```
dependency_overrides:
  # Override path_provider to pick up fixes for FFI changes.
  path_provider: ^2.0.0-nullsafety.1
```

Then run flutter clean and flutter pub get

Comment: It was an issue with an outdated package, don't know which one -- just updated them all! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Might sound stupid, but i ran into similar problems caused by packages not beeing optimized for flutter 2.0 yet. Have you tried to downgrade to flutter 1.2 again ?